# How do I get rich quick?

Tags: terraria

I haven't played Terraria in a while and it has changed a lot, so I want to start over again. What should I do to get some good equipment as quick as possible?
I don't need to have the *epicest* equipment available, but I'd like to be able to roam the world freely, mine where I want, and have some cash.

(I only have a little previous experience with the game. I mostly dug down, found a cave and explored it. Dug even deeper, which took quite a lot of time, found a big cave, died a lot, was too weak, died some more and then moved on to other games.)

Comment: I think that some gold is enough so it seems it could be a possible duplicate of [How to earn gold?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25397/how-to-earn-gold)

Comment: @Drake I think that question is simply about how to actually get *Gold Coins*, not how to make money efficiently. Early in the game, most of the coin drops you get are Silver or Copper, and the fact that they're automatically converted to a higher denomination when the inventory slot overflows is not immediately obvious.

Comment: @lunboks Maybe they are only similar, or maybe these two questions could be merged. It also depends on what ver intend for "rich".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the best solution in the early game is to explore your starting biome and search for shallow caves that contain treasure.  You'll likely find a boomerang early, which can be useful as a ranged and indirect fire weapon early in the game.

Once you've come across a few chests and have a bit of gear/weapons, start [digging a shaft](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBkClus0axY).  Explore caves and fight enemies, which will probably yield some amount of cash plus opportunities to mine ores you can use to forge better equipment.  Better equipment will allow you to dig deeper and/or explore some of the neighboring biomes, which will yield opportunities for even better gear.

Money's not super important as most of the gear in the game can be crafted or found as treasure.  You will need to purchase items from time to time, so make sure that you occasionally make time to satisfy the conditions for [NPCs](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/NPC) to arrive.

Lather, rinse, and repeat until you're epic and difficult to kill, and then you can tackle some of the more exciting boss fights and deepest regions of the world.  If you're at a loss as to what to do next, or how to craft some of the higher level gear, go dig around a bit at one of the [Terraria](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Terraria_Wiki) [Wiki](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Terraria_Wiki) sites, which contain info about all sorts of interesting artifacts.

Death is [relatively cheap](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Penalty), as long as you leave as much of your money as possible at home.  Don't be afraid to go and explore something new, you might luck out and find a valuable artifact.  The worst case scenario is that you end up a tasty snack for something big and nasty, and maybe lose a few coins.

The goal of this game varies depending on what your goal is, so don't be afraid to do something risky or try something new if you're having fun!  If the game is getting frustrating, try exploring more closer to the surface, or looking up a strategy for dealing with the particular situation you're stuck on.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to get what you want is to rush to Eater of Worlds & a set of Demonite equipment.

I've found the fastest way to do that, starting from scratch, is to obtain the following

- At least two pieces of silver armor, or better
- A bow & arrows. Copper is good enough but better will make things faster.
- Ironskin potion. This is the key element - it's frankly overpowered.
- Regeneration potion. Not as strong as Ironskin but very easy to craft.
- A stack of Shuriken

Then you kill the Eye of Cthulu, which drops demonite ore. With demonite alone you can only make the axe, bow & sword.

What you really want is the Dryad, who sells purification powder. This lets you dig through ebonstone and smash shadow orbs. Smashing shadow orbs lets you fight the Eater of Worlds and obtain Shadow Scales, along with even more demonite. (Smashing three orbs is faster than farming for worm food.) Before you venture into the corruption chasms, be sure to obtain a hookshot. When you fight Eater of Worlds for the first few times, use an Ironskin potion. I find that grenades slay Eater very quickly, and they're reasonably accessible.

Summoning Eater a few times through orb busting will net you the highest defense armor short of Hellstone; a pickaxe that can mine every pre-hardmode block; a fair quality sword, axe, bow, and hammer; the musket & arms dealer; and some nifty trinkets.

A full set of Demonite gives enough base defense to farm Eye and Eater without buff potions, and pre-hardmode I am aware of no faster way to obtain coin than farming these bosses & selling their drops. You will also activate the goblin invasion, which you must defeat once for the tinker and mechanic.

In some worlds, the crimson replaces the corruption, which also replaces ebonstone with crimstone, demonite with crimtane, and the Eater of Worlds with Cthulu's Brain. None of these substitutions breaks the overall strategy.

Comment: It's worth noting that the brain o cthulhu is a much tougher fight than the Eater.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I sell my items for money. You should gather tons of life crystals. 1 life crystal is worth 1 gold and 40 silver coins. I got at least 76 gold coins.

BTW, this works for iOS/android, console, and PC. I tried it on all versions just to make sure.

Comment: @Gigazalle I edited my answer so you can delete your comment.

Comment: The fact that you've taken the time to edit your answer to something that provides value to this site is admirable.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: I think in the update they changed the sell price...

Answer (score 3):

When you first start, it should be day. Run along the top of the world to gather wood and kill some slimes. You'll want torches for mining at night. Don't venture down into caves, because you'll want to know when night starts, and it's nice to start your mining near the guide/spawn in case you die (it will happen). As soon as night is near, get back and start mining. Remember that you can build dirt walls behind you while mining to prevent monsters from getting to you.

Caves are dangerous. You can be attacked from all sides, and monsters can spawn just about anywhere off screen. Mining by itself isn't very dangerous, but without caves, isn't a great way to get money. However, you don't need money to get good stuff. Mining iron and silver is a great way to get some decent armor and weapons in the beginning.

If you see treasure chests, jars, or heart containers, mine out to them. Don't be afraid to build dirt walls around you to make gathering loot safe. Make sure you carry a hammer. Remember the 'H' key (you'll find lesser healing potions in those jars, but make sure they come in front of any mushrooms you picked at the surface). Hammering empty chests will allow you to store extra loot and materials near spawn. After a couple day/night cycles, you should have enough materials to build a house for your guide and have decent enough equipment to be a little more reckless. You don't need to house the guide before then (if you find it a matter of honor to house the guide by the first night, you may do so).

For my current character (I restart from scratch every release), I upgraded to a gold pick before I upgraded my initial sword. I skipped gathering copper unless it was near silver/gold/iron. Digging fast made everything easier. Then the money and other loot was relatively easy to acquire.

Frustration tip: avoid playing on a server with lag. I started a game with a friend and had many initial deaths to teleporting demon eyes. I could see someone rage-quitting the game if that was their first time playing.

Comment: lmgtfy is [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler That's why I tried to provide a real answer. Should I edit my answer to remove the initial snark?

Comment: I guess linking to google itself is ok, you _do_ provide an answer but point out that OP is asking for a tutorial which might already have been posted somewhere else. it's just that hiding a google search behind lmgtfy is [rather rude](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: fair enough. Snark removed

Answer (score 2):

What we always end up doing is just exploring starting caves and trying to gather Iron and Wood. Once we had plenty of that, we'd go to the Jungle area and dig into the underground area, build a house with a bed, and just use that as a base of operations; all of the Jungle stuff is decent and a Blade of Grass is one of the easiest mid-tier weapons to get, and the enemies there are (while powerful) a good source of money. You'll need to go down there to get an Ivy Whip at some point anyway, so why not make it early? Bonus points for putting your house on the edge of the underground jungle so you can go through non-Jungle caves at the same time.

The biggest problem with a explore-the-main-caves approach is that the common mobs are pretty cheap and the best you'll be finding is just ore and gems, which you can find in the Jungle anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to become rich in Terraria is to sell golden chests - which are quite rare. BUT, you can duplicate them.

How To Do It:

1. Find a golden chest.
2. Defeat Skeletron which will allow access to the dungeon. If you go far enough into the dungeon you will find the Mechanic. Build a house for her. I make mine 6 blocks tall and 10 blocks wide. Make sure it has wooden or stone background wall with a torch, chair, and table.
3. Buy wire from the Mechanic. Don't forget to buy the wrench for placing wire and the wire cutter for removing it. You also need a lever.
4. Collect two stone blocks.
5. Craft two active stone block. To craft them you will need one stone and one wire.
6. Place the active stone blocks,then mine the blocks under the active stone.
7. Place a golden chest on top of the active stone.
8. Place a lever right beside the active stone blocks.
9. Use the wrench to place the wire. Connect the lever and active stone blocks using wire.
10. Put something in the chest.

FINAL: Constantly flick the lever.

Comment: Does this still work?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the longest part of the game is the first part, before you go corruption/crimson diving. Going underground and looking for silver and gold can take a long time!

So to get past this part quickly and get into the faster progression of the game, I suggest something a little opposite of what you asked: Instead of trying to get the best equipment you can before going into the corruption or crimson, settle somewhat early for moderately good equipment. Once you have mostly silver equipment with a little bit of gold, you should be strong enough to defeat the Eye of Cuthulu and proceed to the next portion of the game. Once you have crimson or corruption-class items, you'll be back on the high end of equipment for how far you are in the game and stay that way until you enter hardmode.

Answer (score 0):

Glitch to create any item you want (Console)

Item Generating Glitch Steps:

1. Backup your save.
2. Disconnect your console from the internet and set the date to Oct 25.
3. Turn off autosave.
4. Purchase X (however many items you want) copies of Dryad Loincloth from the Dryad.
5. Empty out your safe or piggy bank (either, I will say safe to save words).
6. Put the loincloths in the safe.
7. Save from the menu and then return to the main menu without saving.
8. Inside your safe will now be stacks of 1854 iron pickaxes.
9. Remove the number of pickaxes necessary to reach the item you want from this list
   http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Data_IDs
   e.g. If I wanted a stake launcher (data id 1835) I would remove 19 picks and throw them into the trash.
10. Repeat step 7.
11. You will now find the items you wanted to create inside of your safe.

If you want something with an item id higher than 1854 then you will need to look through the list to find something easily obtainable that has such an id and then use that item instead of the loincloth. The number of iron pickaxes corresponds with the data id of the item you placed in the safe.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest beating the Eye of Cthulhu boss; it not only gives you Demonite Ore, but it also gives gold coins. I got 4 coins from it once.